# The relation between topical model and word embedding model

Tags: deep-learning, topic-modeling

I came up with this question when I found a paper named "[topical word embedding](http://nlp.csai.tsinghua.edu.cn/~lzy/publications/aaai2015_twe.pdf)". What is the relation between topical model and word embedding model?

In my opinion, they are both derived version of vector space model, topical model helps u to better understand the document, word embedding helps u to understand the relationship between words. But this is still very abstract, does anyone have a better explanation with examples?

Comment: reference to paper is important

Comment: @NikosM. Thx, already added.

Comment: maybe CS.SE would be more appropriate for this question